# Should I use "Business logic" term when speaking about non-business application?

Tags: terminology, business-logic

Suppose there is a part of program that does not deal with initialisation, input, output. It just specifies what should be done, what is allowed or not. I use the term "Business logic" for this. But application can have nothing to do with business.

Example: a game. Suppose there are following parts:

1. Input processing
2. Collision detection, physics, player control
3. Rendering the output
4. AI - How do NPCs attain the specified goal.
5. "Business logic" - what happens when player touch certain objects. What types of NPCs are there and what they do when ..., concepts of "lives", "ammo", "levels", "score".

But it is not business, it's just a game. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) is not clear about it.

Comment: How about "application logic"?

Comment: "I say Po-tay-to, you say Po-tah-to"..."Six of one, half dozen of the other".  The rules by which the application must run.  Call them what you want, they are what they are.  They MUST be in there for your application to work.

Comment: @Catchops, Is there a strict, official term for a place where such rules are concentrated?

Comment: I tend to call all the things you listed "algorithms"

Comment: @Lambdageek, Algorithms can be used in all parts. Example: algorithms to render 3D image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're feeling weird about it or you're getting push back from others, try using the term **"Domain Logic"** instead.

Comment: depending on context i think 'Model Logic' may be used as well

Answer (score -1):

The essential features of an application are often called "Business Logic".

There are numerous other names.

"Essential Features".

"Model" (as in Model-View-Control).

"Application Logic".

"The Real Work".

You have an unlimited number of synonyms in English for the essential, core, kernel features of a product.  Feel free to use a Thesaurus to find some more.